# Grease Pencil - Drawing screen disappeared

Tags: grease-pencil, 2d

I am not entirely sure what I did, but the screen that lets me draw onto the frames vanished. I think I pressed an up arrow and then it disappeared, and I'm not sure how to recover it

[image: greasepencil screen]

Comment: Currently trying to upload a very helpful gif to show you what to do but my god is keeping under 2mb hard

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a shortcut to undo a viewport move?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40626/is-there-a-shortcut-to-undo-a-viewport-move)